# Flask webservice won't receive external message

Tags: c#, python, azure, flask

My situation:

Python webservice on local machine:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/subscribe', methods=['POST'])
def subscribe():

    //Do webservice work...

    return "completed"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

C# webservice in Azure Cloud:

```
public static async Task SendSubscriptionAsync(string deviceName)
{
  var client = new RestClient();
  client.BaseUrl = new Uri("http://{IP adress}:5000");

  var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);

  request.Resource = "subscribe";
  request.AddParameter("deviceName", deviceName, ParameterType.QueryString);

  IRestResponse response = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request);
  var content = response.Content;
 }
```

When I run the C# webservice local, the Python webservice receives the messages.

But when I run the C# webservice from Azure Cloud, the Python webservice does not receive the messages.

I have read the [Flask Quickstart manuel](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#quickstart). 
How come Python won't receive external messages?

Comment: Trying to access local IP from outside of your LAN with no port forwarding?

Comment: If you are running the flask server on your computer at home and the webservice somewhere else then it is neither a problem with flask nor with python. You should read about NAT: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Port_forwarding

Comment: I wasn't aware of such a thing as port forwarding. I will have a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding, you want to request the Flask service on the local from the C# client on Azure.

Per my experience, the simple way is that configuring your local router with the port forwarding and a dynamic DNS for the ADSL dynamic IP, then the C# client can access the domain name with the specified WAN port of the router.

If your router not support these features, I think you can try to use the Azure Service Bus to create the communication between the local Flask service and the cloud C# service.

The principle is that creating a pair of Service Bus Queue for sending and receiving between both services as below.

- The Cloud C# service send a JSON message as request to Queue 1, then the local Flask service receive the JSON message via polling and parse the message to the arguments for working.

  > local Flask service <------ Queue 1 <------- cloud C# service
- The local Flask service send the completed result as a message to Queue 2, then the cloud C# service receive the result message via polling.

  > local Flask service ------> Queue 2 -------> cloud C# service